# No insertar datos repetidos a MYSQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Estoy tratando de subir unos archivos a MySQL como proyecto, pero el problema es que si selecciono el archivo 2 o más veces él vuelve y los sube.

La idea es hacer que cuando intente subir el archivo lea las filas y diga que **X** cantidad de celdas ya se subieron, o si ya todo el archivo subió entonces que lo muestre.

Lo estoy tratando de hacer por MYSQL, más no sé si sea el camino más óptimo.

```
IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT carnet FROM Tabla_Carnet (NOLOCK) WHERE carnet = XXXXX )
BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Tabla_Carnet( carnet, fecha)
        VALUES( carnet, GETDATE() )
END
```

Acá es lo que estoy insertando, por ende, son los mismos datos del archivo XLSX

```
$sql  = 'INSERT INTO Tabla_Carnet (                         fecha,
                                                            carnet,
                                                            hora,
                                                            nombre,
                                                            apellido,
                                                            sexo,
                                                            edad,
                                                            ocupacion,
                                                            estudios,
                                                            discapacidad)
                                        VALUES(             "'.$data.'",
                                                            "'.$hora.'",
                                                            "'.$data[2].'",
                                                            "'.$data[3].'",
                                                            "'.$data[6].'",
                                                            "'.$data[7].'",
                                                            "'.$data[8].'",
                                                            "'.$data[9].'",
                                                            "'.$data[10].'",
                                                          "'.$data[12].'")';

                $contador++;
```

Donde se ejecuta el $sql

```
if ($data[7] != '') 
                    {
                    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

                    if (!$sql)
                        {
                        echo '<div>¡Oh, detectamos un problema! 
                            <br>¡Por favor vuelva a intentarlo!</div>';
                        exit;
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Creo que deberías explicar mejor todo el proceso de lo que estás realizando para ayudarte mejor

Comment: ¿estás subiendo un archivo plano? ¿procesandolo completo o cada fila? ¿por qué no haces una tabla que guarde el nombre del archivo el número de filas junto con id y comparas dicha información con el archivo que subas?

Comment: Estoy procesando un archivo de excel, estoy leyendo todas las filas del archivo y con eso que lo suba a la base de datos... ¿cuál es el problema? **que si vuelvo a seleccionar el archivo otra vez para subirlo, él vuelve y lo sube con los mismos valores.,**

Comment: Lo que quiero es el php o mysql detecten que si los datos de las celdas del archivo ya están en la base de datos, entonces que no haga nada,  o que de lo contrario, que suba las celdas que faltan. O si es un nuevo archivo, que lo suba completo, y si luego se va a intentar subir el mismo archivo, que pase exactamente igual, que indique que ya se encuentra en la base de datos.

Comment: Puedes **[edit]** tu pregunta y añadir lo que tengas de código en PHP, el formato del achivo, etc

Comment: Tu descripción del problema es a muy alto nivel, y no incluye detalles importantes; en primer lugar qué significa/cómo se detecta que un archivo (o una fila) esté repetido...

Comment: Ya agregué al código cómo estoy leyendo los datos de las filas.

Comment: Lo que quieres hacer creo que que es verificar si existen los registros que vienen desde el excel, para eso tienes que hacer un select antes del insert, me explico, el select tiene que jalar los datos de la fila que estas leyendo en ese momento, si el select no devuelve valores, entonces es porque no existe en la base de datos, entonces haces el insert, si el select devuelve valores entonces no se inserta y se continua con la siguiente fila.

Comment: Muy bien el análisis, pero ¿Cómo sería el código? :D

Comment: ¿Hay algún campo que sea **único** @CarlosOrtiz ? Si es así declaralo como tal en la tabla y listo. La consulta fallará si se repite dicho campo.

Comment: Voy a poner un ejemplo,  **Juan entregó la tarea en la fecha 01/09/2017, a las 09:32.** Así mismo con todos los estudiantes, entonces ¿Cuál es el problema? que eso ya está en una base de datos en excel, pero si yo vuelvo a subir ese archivo, él me lo vuelve a subir,  la idea es que **NO lo vuelva a subir si ya está en la base de datos**. Entonces no sabría decir si hay algún campo único, porque todos tienen fechas diferentes, horas diferentes, lo que necesito es que no vuelva a subir un archivo que ya había subido.

Comment: Lo solucionaste o aun necesitas ayuda?

Comment: @juliocpiro No, no lo he solucionado y si, por favor, necesito ayuda.

Comment: Por favor agrega las lineas donde ejecutas el $sql para guiarme que `funcion` para ejecutar estas usando. Tambien necesitas un identificador de los datos, podria ser el `carnet` de modo que si llega ese carnet ya sabrias que son datos repetidos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Valor Hash**

Si te encuentras que debes validar entre dos archivos, la mejor forma de proceder sería calculando el hash de dicho archivo y este valor compararlo con los que tienes almacenados.

Aquí te dejo la documentación de como generar el hash
http://php.net/manual/es/function.sha1-file.php

```
<?php
foreach(glob('/home/Kalle/myproject/*.php') as $ent)
{
    if(is_dir($ent))
    {
        continue;
    }

    echo $ent . ' (SHA1: ' . sha1_file($ent) . ')', PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

Después de obtener el hash de un archivo, lo guardas en un campo extra, el próximo archivo que deseas subir, generas el hash y lo comparas contra este campo.

Detectará hasta el más mínimo cambio en un archivo.

Comment: Pero la verdad no sé dónde ponerlo o realmente cómo funcione.